# I have an issue which can't solve with npm laravel

Tags: laravel, npm

I'm new at LARAVEL. I have an setup issue with NPM I can't solve it from a while.

this is the error comes for me

```
> > node-sass@4.10.0 install C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-67_binding.node
Download complete  ] - :
Binary saved to C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-67\binding.node
Caching binary to C:\Users\Di7aa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.10.0\win32-x64-67_binding.node

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\node_modules\laravel-mix\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-67\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1269 packages from 706 contributors and audited 17986 packages in 186.49s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

---

anyOne can help please ?

Comment: So, specifically, what are you concerned about? I don't see any output there that suggests the command failed.

Comment: I edited your question so it's easier to read. You can learn how to format it properly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). I used formatting for "code and preformatted text".

Answer (score 1):

Just run `npm audit fix`, everything is fine, you have no errors.

Comment: where i Can find npm audit fix ??

Comment: it's a command, just run it in a terminal/cmd in the root folder of your laravel application